# In WooCommerce I am getting error in checkout page kindly read the error below

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

> Please make sure that your card details have been entered correctly and that your browser supports JavaScript. Developers: Please make sure that you're including jQuery and that there are no JavaScript errors in the page.

in checkout page.

Any idea where the problem could be situated?

Comment: You don't have jquery loaded on your checkout page. Have you tried setting your checkout page in the Woocommerce settings?

Comment: yes..i have checked it's loaded, kindly check you also this is url :\

Comment: http://www.gemconnection.com/checkout/

Comment: Try disabling some plugins you have loaded. I've found on line that "It seems that Wordpress 4.3 has introduced new security measures that the ChangeTip plugin does not adhere to.". So if you have that plugin, or some similar plugin, try disabling it and see if you get errors.

Comment: What plugin are you using for credit card?

Comment: i am using YITH WooCommerce Stripe Premium.